# Execute different pieces of code based on a value in C#

Tags: c#, azure, class, httprequest

I have a piece of C# code that reacts to an HTTP trigger from Azure and gets executed. The piece of code sends an email containing a warning:

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "SendGrid"
using System;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static SendGridMessage Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
    log.LogInformation(requestBody);
    var notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Notification>>(requestBody);

    SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
    message.Subject = "Sensor Anomaly Warning";

    var content = "The following device has started registering anomalies:<br/><br/><table><tr><th>time</th><th>value</th><th>lower bound</th><th>upper bound</th><th>device</th></tr>";
    foreach(var notification in notifications) {
        log.LogInformation($" -  time: {notification.time}, value: {notification.value}, lowerbound: {notification.lowerbound}, upperbound: {notification.upperbound}, device: {notification.device}");
        content += $"<tr><td>{notification.time}</td><td>{notification.value}</td><td>{notification.lowerbound}</td><td>{notification.upperbound}</td><td>{notification.device}</td></tr>";
    }
    content += "</table>";
    message.AddContent("text/html", content);  

    return message;
}

public class Notification
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string lowerbound { get; set; }
    public string upperbound { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to execute this same piece of code that sends an email, but based on the value of `notification.alert` which stores a zero if an anomaly started and a 1 if the alert stopped. Coming from python, this would be as easy as setting an "if else" statement, where the function is called in each case.

However for this C# code, there is no function to call. The piece of code sends an email but it's just creating a class. In any case, I'm wondering if I can use a "if else" statement in C# based on the value of  `notification.alert` that in one case sends an email saying something like "the device has started registering anomalies" and in the other "the device has stopped registering anomalies". I just can't get to do this, as I have to address the `notification` object, which is already inside the class.

I must say that I am not a C# developer but a Python developer, hence the doubts.

Comment: `there is no function to call.` that snippet is full of function calls. `SendGridMessage` is a function calling other functions. If you want to change the content, use `if`, `switch` etc. `content +=` appends a string to another. `$"<tr><td>{notification.time}"` is the same as an f-string in Python

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but what is the function that explicitly sends the email? that is, what is the part of this snippet I should divide in cases into the if else statement? I'm thinking it should be from the "SendGridMessage message" part on, but I don't know if that's the function call I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if/else statement or switch to update the email body based on `notification.alert`. this function is not sending the email it's just setting up a message for the email body text.

```
using System;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static SendGridMessage Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
    log.LogInformation(requestBody);
    var notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Notification>>(requestBody);

SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
message.Subject = "Sensor Anomaly Warning";

var content = "The following device has started registering anomalies:   <br/><br/><table><tr><th>time</th><th>value</th><th>lower bound</th><th>upper bound</th><th>device</th></tr>";
foreach(var notification in notifications) {
    log.LogInformation($" -  time: {notification.time}, value: {notification.value}, lowerbound: {notification.lowerbound}, upperbound: {notification.upperbound}, device: {notification.device}");
    content += notification.alert == 0 ? "the device has started registering anomalies" : "the device has stopped registering anomalies";
}
content += "</table>";
message.AddContent("text/html", content);  

return message;
}

public class Notification
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string lowerbound { get; set; }
    public string upperbound { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public int alert { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: works fine! but what if I wanted to not call at all the function when the notification.alert is zero, and send the email (call the function) when the notification.alert=1? can it be done?

Comment: which function? `SendGridMessage` or the function that sends the email?

Comment: I mean the function that sends the email. I thought they were the same

Comment: this function just prepares the message of the email to be sent. you need a client like SMTP client  `using var client = new SmtpClient();` to connect to through the socket and then authenticate the client, and finally send email `await client.SendAsync(message);` that will be the function that sends the email. have a look at [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-email-in-csharp-dotnet-using-smtp-and-sendgrid).